# UITableView Push to Multiple Views with Different URL Data

Tags: iphone

I'm relatively new to iPhone Development and I'm trying to create an app that's using a UITableView that needs to push to different Views. Right now I'm designing it to push to a different page each time a cell is clicked. It seems that from other posts that I've read that it's not a good idea as there will be a lot of individual View pages. I'm not sure how to accomplish this as I am designing each View to have a phone number, email, web site and SMS that goes to different sources/destinations. I've designed everything up to this point and it works, but need this final step in order to finalize the app. Any help or tutorial that someone could be point me to would be appreciated.

I'll try to be more specific. I have a main menu of categories that navigates to a submenu of other categories. Each category that the submenu navigates to has a phone link, email link, SMS link, and web link. Do I have to make separate pages/views for each category or is there a way to make a NSDictionary that will house all of the data for each category that has the URL links?

Comment: You may need to be more specific about what you're working with, but this link should point you in the right direction. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific in your question.  It sounds as if you wish to push a subsequent UITableViewController onto a UINavigationController stack using a 'push' segue, with the data passed to the sub-category using a combination of the methods 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath:' to determine the clicked row, and 'prepareForSegue:' to pass the row data to the new UITableViewController.

Check out the Apple tutorial - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/ which covers all of these concepts in very simple terms.